# CSS Auto fill Grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am currently trying to make my grid auto-fill so it will automatically move around depending on page size. However, by standard it is a straight row. But I want it to move some of the boxes down a row. For example 4 on row 1 and 2 on row 2

For example, It does this by default:
[image]

But I want it like below but I still want to automatically adjust where the box's are depending on page size. (I done this by changing auto-fill to 4, but it stops it from automatically adjusting)

[image]

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid !important;
  grid-gap: 10px !important;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(115px, 115px)) !important;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;

}

.grid-container p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #959595;
  font-weight: 630 !important;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.Test-item {
  background-color: BLUE;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 85px !important;
  float: left !important;
  color: #959595 !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  line-height: 14px !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="Test-item 1 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="Test-item 2 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="Test-item 3 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="Test-item 4 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="Test-item 5 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Test-item 6 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone see what I am missing ?

Comment: use flex-box instead. you can read more by googling it :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem-- when changing the viewport size in your snippet the grid items automatically are flowing to the next line-- is that not the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by using `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` Using the `flex-wrap` allows for your test items to automatically wrap into a new row when resizing the browser. Feel free to change as necessary.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  
}

.grid-container p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #959595;
  font-weight: 630 !important;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.Test-item {
  background-color: BLUE;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 85px !important;
  float: left !important;
  color: #959595 !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  line-height: 14px !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .grid-container {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="container">
<div class="grid-container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="Test-item 1 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="Test-item 2 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="Test-item 3 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="Test-item 4 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="Test-item 5 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Test-item 6 clickable" onclick="window.open('google.com', '_blank');"><img src="TEST1" />
    <p>test1</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```